# log_error method in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-log

I'm switching my application to Rails 3 and for the moment I discover some problems with the log_error method. In the doc ( http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Rescue/log_error ) they say that the last version is in 2.3.8 so in this case it is normal that it is not working.

But when I check then the alternatives, they propose http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/ShowExceptions/log_error which is supported in rails 3. But still he's telling me "undefined method log_error".

I use it in my application controller as following:

```rb
def render_not_found(exception = nil)
  log_error(exception) if exception
  #notify_hoptoad(exception)
  render :template => "/help/404.html.erb", :status => 404
end

def render_error(exception)
  log_error(exception)
  notify_hoptoad(exception)
  render :template => "/help/500.html.erb", :status => 500
end
```

How can I use the method log_error in Rails 3 then? Or is there an alternative for this method?

Answer (score 1):

Method you want to use is `private` so you cannot call it explicitly.
 I think you should use something like this to show exception:

```
message = "\n#{exception.class} (#{exception.message}):\n"
Rails.logger.warn(messafe)
```

It is just a guess, so you free to customize it for your needs.

Comment: I expanded on that to use this: `Rails.logger.error("\n#{exception.class} (#{exception.message}):\n  #{Rails.backtrace_cleaner.clean(exception.backtrace).join("\n  ")}")`